# ip rule shouldn't beat ip route

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, route

I'm running CentOS and are using `ip route` and `ip rule` for routing.

I've currently got an `ip rule`

```
from 10.8.23.0/28 table 1234
```

and `ip route`

```
default via 10.8.23.254 eth1
10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.1 eth1
10.0.0.0/14 dev test-interface table 1234
```

It seems my `ip rule` succeds the second line in `ip route`, so even if destination IP is 10.10.10.10 my packets are still sent via `test-interface` if source IP is `10.8.23.0/28`.

How can I make sure that `10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.1 eth1` overrules the ìp rule` even when the source IP matches the rule? Hope it make sense :)

Testing `ip route get 10.10.10.10` gives me:

```
10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.1 dev eth1  src 10.8.23.1
```

but `ip route get 10.10.10.10 src 10.0.0.13` gives me:

```
10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.254 dev test-interface  src 10.8.23.1
```

So `src IP` is prioritized over destination IP.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but the whole idea of policy based routing is that you use `ip rule` to define which routing table should be used for a given policy.

Comment: I would like the specific destination IP 10.10.10.10 to be prioritized over everything else, so that is routed via interface eth1, and not net-interface.

Comment: I think you could just use a higher-priority rule for that exception.

Comment: I've added the route with `ip route add 10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.1 dev eth1`. how can I add a priority which is higher the the `ip rule add...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply think of `ip rule` is that it is a way to create/have more ip routing tables (not just the default one).

To solve your issue, you need to add another `ip rule` entry to handle your specific route case. For example, you can use the following command:

```
$ sudo ip rule add to 10.10.10.10/32 lookup 123 priority 10
```

Here, I am assuming `10` is small enough to be the first `ip rule`. This depends on the output of `ip rule ls`. It will show you all rules according to priority (a smaller value means higher priority and is shown first).

If you need to combine source and destination checks in your `ip rule`, you can use:

```
$ sudo ip rule add from 10.8.23.0/28 to 10.10.10.10/32 lookup 123 priority 10
```

The table `123` should contain the right route such as:

```
$ sudo ip route add 10.10.10.10/32 via 10.10.10.1 table 123
```

Comment: `lookup 123` should that then point to eth1 in some way?

Comment: @KasperNielsen: You need to add your route `10.10.10.10 via 10.10.10.1 eth1` to this table `123` to complete the config. I updated my answer!