# Packets routed through wrong interface

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route, iproute2

This is a follow up on [ip rule shouldn't beat ip route](https://serverfault.com/questions/898192/ip-rule-shouldnt-beat-ip-route).

I've configured everything as per my last question.
But...

Running:

```
$ ip route get 10.10.10.10 from 10.0.0.13 iif test-interface
10.10.10.10 from 10.0.0.13 via 10.10.10.1 dev eth1
cache  iif test-interface
```

But `tshark -i eth1` show no packets, but `tshark -i test-interface` show the packets when sending traffic to 10.10.10.10 from 10.0.0.13.

What to do... really lost...

Output of `ip route ls`

```
default via 10.8.23.254 dev eth1
10.10.10.10 via 10.8.23.254 dev eth1
10.0.0.0/14 dev test-interface  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
```

Output of `ip rule ls`

```
ip rule ls
0:  from all lookup local
10: from 10.0.0.0/14 to 10.10.10.10 lookup 1234
100:    from 10.0.0.1/14 lookup test-interface
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Output of `ip route show table 1234`

```
default via 10.8.23.254 dev eth1
10.10.10.10 via 10.8.23.254 dev eth1
```

Comment: Please, the output of `ip rule ls` and the content of routing tables `ip route ls`.

Comment: Updated with output...

Comment: Any comments on `ip rule ls` and `ip route ls` ?

Comment: I've even tried to add the following `iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -d 10.10.10.10 -o eth1`, and `iptables -t mangle -nvL` shows packets hitting that rule. But tshark only shows packets on the `test-interface`.

Comment: Isn't there any "simple" way to see which rules and routes are actually hit when packets comes from test-interface with destination IP 10.10.10.10?